# Having a "value in list" condition when using JQ's Golang implementation

Tags: go, jq

I am using this library in my Go app: https://github.com/itchyny/gojq
It's working perfectly fine but I cannot find in JQ documentation how to do something. I have a jq query which input is a list of available stores in a config file that looks like this:

```
( [.stores[] | select( .is_open == true )] | length  > 1 ) 
     and 
( [.stores[] | select( .name == "Some store" )] | length == 1 )
```

Basically says that from the list of available stores in my area at least one is open and also, from the list of available stores in my area at least one is called "Some store". ( Notice that its two SEPARATED conditions, I dont care if "Some store" is closed ).

Now I need to change this condition so instead of having the second condition to look into the name, every store will have a "type_identifier" which is a string. And basically what I want is to have something like:

```
( [.stores[] | select( .type_identifier in ["type1","type2", "type2"...] )] | length == 1 )
```

Where the list of available types have like 600 different types.
So my questions are:

1. Is there a "in" selector in JQ. What would be the right syntax?
2. The list of available "types" is another field of the same object along with the list of stores, how can I read the list directly from this property?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The "in" filter you are looking for is called `IN` (all caps), and resolves as `def IN(src; s): any(src == s; .);`. If you provide some actual input data, we could demonstrate its usage. -- gojq is a rewrite of [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/), so you can take its [manual](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/) as reference, while keeping an eye on the [minor differences](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq#difference-to-jq) between the two implementations.

Comment: Probably involving binding a variable to an array of types. Something along the lines of `.where.the.types.live as $types | … | (.stores[] | select(IN(.type_identifier; $types[]))) | …`.

Comment: Thanks! @pmf! It worked with a slight difference in syntaxis. I ended up with something like this:
``` select( .type | IN($types[]) )```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is that long, best to create a lookup table.

```
(
   [ "type1", "type2", "type3" ] |
   map( { (.): true } ) |
   add
) as $lkup |

.stores |
( map( select( .is_open ) ) | length > 1 )
   and
( map( select( $lkup[ .type_identifier ] ) ) | length == 1 )
```

I factored out the common `.stores`, and I replaced `[ .[] | ... ]` with `map( ... )`.

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rI85iwBijWq) on jqplay.

---

You could also use `INDEX`.

```
(
   [ "type1", "type2", "type3" ] |
   INDEX( .[]; . )
) as $lkup |

.stores |
( map( select( .is_open ) ) | length > 1 )
   and
( map( select( $lkup[ .type_identifier ] ) ) | length == 1 )
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/heOiuYDUBOT) on jqplay.